# Reactivity for root props in Vue when they are external JS classes

Tags: vue.js, keycloak, keycloak-javascript

When creating an Vue (v3) application, you can start it by calling createApp with your main component in main.js file:

```
createApp({
      render () {
        return h(App, props)
      }
}
```

where App is your main component and props are root props you pass to your component. Until here everything is fine. The problem comes when using as a prop an external JS class. Even if you want to make it reactive, so you can detect changes in your root props, it won't work:

```
const props = reactive({ keycloak: keycloak })
```

How is it possible to make it work with a class root prop?

The particular problem I found it when using this guide https://www.keycloak.org/securing-apps/vue for integrating keycloack (OAuth2 Identity Provider) with a Vue application and I have problems with the reactivity of the token obtained.

As you can see in the code, there is a timer that calls a function that updates the object *keycloak*, but this changes are not being shown in the components of the application, they just keep the first value. Something I consider wrong as the whole point of this particular problem is having an update token to use in your components.

Note: the example is in Vue 2, but it is not working either with 2 or 3 version.

```
let initOptions = {
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth', realm: 'keycloak-demo', clientId: 'app-vue', onLoad: 'login-required'
}

let keycloak = Keycloak(initOptions);

keycloak.init({ onLoad: initOptions.onLoad }).then((auth) => {
  if (!auth) {
    window.location.reload();
  } else {
    Vue.$log.info("Authenticated");

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      render: h => h(App, { props: { keycloak: keycloak } })
    })
  }


//Token Refresh
  setInterval(() => {
    keycloak.updateToken(70).then((refreshed) => {
      if (refreshed) {
        Vue.$log.info('Token refreshed' + refreshed);
      } else {
        Vue.$log.warn('Token not refreshed, valid for '
          + Math.round(keycloak.tokenParsed.exp + keycloak.timeSkew - new Date().getTime() / 1000) + ' seconds');
      }
    }).catch(() => {
      Vue.$log.error('Failed to refresh token');
    });
  }, 6000)

}).catch(() => {
  Vue.$log.error("Authenticated Failed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

my answer comes a bit later but you can try this in main.ts:

```
    import App from './App.vue'
    import Keycloak from "keycloak-js"
    
    const keycloakOptions = {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/',
        realm: 'myRealm',
        clientId: 'myClient',
        'public-client': true,
        'verify-token-audience': false
    }
    
    const keycloak = Keycloak(keycloakOptions)
    const appKcProps = reactive({ keycloak: keycloak })
    
    keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required'}).then((auth) => {
        if (!auth) {
          window.location.reload();
        } else {
          console.log("Authenticated");
        }  
      
        //Token Refresh
        setInterval(() => {
          keycloak.updateToken(70).then((refreshed) => {
            if (refreshed) {
                console.log('Token refreshed' + refreshed);
            } else {
                console.log('Token not refreshed, valid for ' + keycloak.tokenParsed?.exp  + ' seconds');
            }
          }).catch(() => {
            console.log('Failed to refresh token');
          });
        }, 6000)
      
      }).catch(() => {
        console.log("Authenticated Failed");
    })
    
    createApp({ 
            render(){
                return h(App, appKcProps)
            } 
        })
        .use(store)
        .use(router)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).